# Responsive table or bootstraps grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out the best way to make a certain page responsive.  https://secure.taxcollector.com/ptaxweb/ if you hit accept it brings you to the page I am trying to make responsive using bootstrap.

As of right now I have a table but when I use the table it messes up the spacing of my buttons:

```
<table class="display responsive no-wrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>1. SEARCH PROPERTIES BY CLICKING <u>ONE</u> OF THE FOLLOWING BUTTONS:</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByActiveButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('accountNumber')" value="PROPERTY ID" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('name')" value="OWNER NAME" id="name" name="name" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('location')" value="PROPERTY ADDRESS" id="location" name="location" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('billingAddress')" value="BILLING ADDRESS" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

or...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><strong>1. SEARCH PROPERTIES BY CLICKING <u>ONE</u> OF THE FOLLOWING BUTTONS:</strong></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="searchoptions" class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="name" name="name">OWNER NAME</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="location" name="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Would it be better to use the grid system instead? Is it possible to recreate these tables and just use bootstraps grid systems to make it responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make bootstrap tabes responsive as well..just use `class='table responsive'`

**check snippet**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
   <table class="display table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>1. SEARCH PROPERTIES BY CLICKING <u>ONE</u> OF THE FOLLOWING BUTTONS:</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByActiveButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('accountNumber')" value="PROPERTY ID" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('name')" value="OWNER NAME" id="name" name="name" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('location')" value="PROPERTY ADDRESS" id="location" name="location" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="searchByButton" onclick="changeSearchBy('billingAddress')" value="BILLING ADDRESS" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
  </html>
```

**evenly spaced buttonds using grid system**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            .btn-sm {
              display: inline-block;
            }
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row">
 
        <h1><strong>1. SEARCH PROPERTIES BY CLICKING <u>ONE</u> OF THE FOLLOWING BUTTONS:</strong></h1>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="button" class="searchByActiveButton btn-xs" onclick="changeSearchBy('accountNumber')" value="PROPERTY ID" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" />
            
            <input type="button" class="searchByButton btn-xs" onclick="changeSearchBy('name')" value="OWNER NAME" id="name" name="name" />
            <input type="button" class="searchByButton btn-xs" onclick="changeSearchBy('location')" value="PROPERTY ADDRESS" id="location" name="location" />
            <input type="button" class="searchByButton btn-xs" onclick="changeSearchBy('billingAddress')" value="BILLING ADDRESS" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress" /></div>
        
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: do you see the buttons though? the four buttons should be evenly spaced in between. Thats what I am unable to figure out. Because the first button is having the spacing of the label above it. But upvote for answering :)

Comment: pretty sure also i had responsive which also does the same right?

Comment: no there is no native class called responsive in bootstrap 3..I have adde another snipet for evenly spaced button to complete my answer